# How do I simulate a website-login in iOS-app?

Tags: ios, http, httprequest

I want to program an app that logs into a website with user/pw and then downloads some data from the website (actually I just want to check if a specific tag is present).
I'm generally familiar with app development (UI, data, etc.) but have never delved into "networking-stuff", especially not http.
According to my research so far, it should work as follows: 1. Examine the login-post request in the browser's dev tools. 2. Send an post-request in the app 3. Wait for a response and download.
I can do step 3 for any website, but I can't find any tutorials/examples for steps 1 and 2 (analyzing and performing the login-process) that explain it in a way I understand. I don't know what terms to look for either. Does somebody has any idea? A rough overview or just a few bullet points would suffice.

Comment: use `WkWebView`

Comment: Doesn't work for me (as far as I know). As a background application, the app should check the website at regular intervals and give a notification if necessary.